# Does having a non-static ip stop you from port forwarding?

Tags: portforwarding

I've been trying to port forward on my router for the last couple days with little success. I just realized that my IP is not in fact static as it is supposed to be, would this cause ports to show as closed?

Comment: No. But do ask with more detail at Server Fault, this is off-topic on SO

Comment: No. But, many ISP's limit port availability for non-static addresses. High ports are usually fine, it is the normal server port ranges you need that they block -- on purpose to drive you to a fixed IP and $30-$70 more per-month...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not of course.

You can open ports on your firewall. 
The problem is that your ip will change and someone to find you again needs the new one. Find your new one there http://whatismyipaddress.com/

You can work with a dns manager like http://www.noip.com/ to have a dns name.
Also the problem with the firewall ports is that your computer will change your IPV4 address and then you must edit your port configs again. Go to run->cmd->write ipconfig and see that your ip is different now.

Answer (score 0):

No, if you setup port forwarding, it will work regardless of what your external IP address is and will remain in place even if your external IP address changes.  In other words, traffic will be forwarded to the internal IP address on port you specify, even if the external IP address changes.

Now, the trick is going to be finding out your external IP address when you are working remotely.  This is one creative way:
http://lifehacker.com/5737187/use-dropbox-to-find-the-ip-address-of-your-remote-computers

If you're having other issues, try looking into the firewall settings of your computer.